# Thymeleaf download attribute

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

In my Thymeleaf template I am able to process Java-map content to html like this:

```
<div th:each="file : ${files}">
     <span th:text="${file.key}"></span> <!-- here file.key is readed -->
     ----
</div>
```

Then I try to add html [download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute that specifies the name of downloaded file:

```
<a th:href="..." th:download="${file.key}" > Download </a>
```

but the th:download attribute is not processed on the server, the generated html looks like this:

```
<a th:download="${file.key}" href="...ok..."> Download </a>
```

How could I get access to file.key property and add it to download-attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the value of arbitrary attributes (not just the ones Thymeleaf supports) then you can use `th:attr`. ([Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute)). eg:

```
<a th:href="..." th:attr="download=${file.key}" > Download </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version (3.0.11) from Thymeleaf is the `th:download` attribute support. The solution from Andrew is now not necessary.